# Bibtex for Geological Society of America (GSA) Format?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Is there a bibliography style file in BibTeX for the Geological Society of America (GSA) format? Otherwise, is there a way I can easily create my own BibTeX style (or anything similar) — like super easy for a LaTeX novice? For example, GSA format looks like this: (author, year, title, journal, volume, number, pages)

[image: GSA Format Example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Real quick: Have you asked the journal's editorial board whether they provide a suitable bibliography style file?

Comment: If I read https://www.geosociety.org/ correctly, then GSA journals usually expect submissions in MS Word. So if you want to submit a paper to the a GSA journal you probably shouldn't be using LaTeX at all. I doubt there is any official LaTeX bibliography style and a short web search didn't reveal anything unofficial either. ...

Comment: ... If you just need GSA style for some other purpose (thesis, a grant proposal, ... something else you can submit in PDF), you could look into creating a BibTeX style with https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib. `makebst` is pretty simple because you just have to answer questions about your style, but it can't cater for every eventuality, so some manual tweaking may be required (which may or may not be painful).

Comment: A quick check of the [GSA website](https://www.geosociety.org/GSA/Publications/Journals/GSA/Pubs/journals.aspx?hkey=81962575-b67f-475d-9f6f-07e9a0bd12c4) reveals that the GSA actually publishes five [5] separate journals. Which one in particular are you interested in?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I'm using LaTex for my thesis because I hate figure management in Word, but I think I will just append a Reference page I make in Word.